# Measure Theory with Limsup and Liminf

Tags: measure-theory

I have one answer to this question and I am looking for another answer.  The reason I am looking for another answer is because this question was on a qualifying exam for real analysis and doesn't seem to use any major theorems so I'm curious if there's some other obvious solution which uses something more (continuity from above/below, dominated convergence, or fubini/tonelli).

Suppose $(X,\cal M, \mu)$ is a measure space with $\mu(X)<\infty$. Suppose further that $A_n$ and $B_n$ are sequences of sets such that $\mu(\limsup A_n) = \mu(\liminf B_n) = \mu(X)$.

**Prove that $\mu(\limsup A_n \cap B_n) = \mu(X)$.**

One solution:

Observe that $\mu(\limsup A_n \cap \liminf B_n) = \mu(X)$.  Then note that if $x \in \limsup A_n \cap \liminf B_n$, then $x \in A_n$ for infinitely many $n$ and $x \in B_n$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Therefore $x$ is in $A_n \cap B_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

Therefore $\limsup A_n \cap \liminf B_n \subset \limsup A_n \cap B_n$.  Thus by the monotonicity of measure, $\mu(X) = \mu(\limsup A_n \cap \liminf B_n) \leq \mu(\limsup A_n \cap B_n) \leq \mu(X)$ and the claim is proven.